# BIOS/UEFI Setup for ASUS Q270M-C desktop motherboad has no Easy Flash option

Tags: windows-7, bios, uefi

I'm trying to upgrade BIOS on my new ASUS Q270M-C and there is no Easy Flash option under Advanced in the BIOS setup. The current version is 0303 64-bit.  (Aptio Setup Utility v 2.17.1246)

I downloaded the latest BIOS update (.CAP file, ver 0602) but I'm not sure how to apply it.

I found some ASUS instructions on using WinFlash from within Windows, but I don't know where to download WinFlash. I would prefer to do it from within the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on another Superuser question: **Push Alt-F2 during POST** and the ASUS EzFlash Utility will open.  Use arrow keys to select current drive (my USB and hard drive are available as FS0 and FS1) and then browse directory to find the PRIME-Q270M-C-ASUS-0602.CAP file.